# No errors when submitting comment, leaving blank area if webpage is idle for long time

Tags: javascript, ajax, xpages, intervals

I have an Xpage that submits data using partial refresh. I have noticed that if I leave the webpage open for a very long time and submit a comment the partial refresh is not returning anything after submit. leaving the area blank. and the comment is not saved.

When I look in developer tools I can se the request being submitted with status 200 but nothing is returned.

I have several intervall timers running on the page so there should be no scope timeouts and all users are anonymous. and these "request timers" seem to work fine even before I submit the comment

I also use hijackPartialRefresh to log the request but it does not return any errors.

I am using server page persistence: keep pages in memory with max 16 pages in memory. (don't ask)

What could be the cause of this and is there anything I can do to make sure my comments are submitted or at least leave an error. (instead of blank area)

Thanks
Thomas